# Trying To Force a New Line via CSS - Display:block Not Working

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to get a div to take up a full line, and force a new line for the next div, which normally would be achieved by using `display:block` in the css for the first `div` - as far as I understand. But it's not working for me. Not sure what I'm missing. To clarify, the `div` I'm trying to take up a full line is the **flags-right** `div` class. Right now it's showing up on the same line as the **photo**, which is aligned left. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="flags-right">
    <div class="red-circle"></div>
    <div class="blue-circle"></div>
    <div class="yellow-circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo"><img [src]="rkPhoto" alt="photo" /></div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
  .flags-right {
      float: right;
      display: block
  }

  .photo {
    float: left;
    height: 4.563rem;
    width: 4.688rem;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.red-circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background: #f9646a;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
.blue-circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    background: #54a6f4;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  .yellow-circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fcff26;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
```

And here's the CSS for the container element:

```
  .col-1-4 {
    background: @containerBgColor;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: @flagText;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: 24%;
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add:

```
clear:both;
```

When using floats, "display:block" won't cause a div to be on a "new line" (display:block is the default for a div anyway). You have to use clear to tell it to start below any floats that come before it.

Comment: Ah, of course, I always forget about "clear:both". That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer with the tick as it solved it for you. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, so "display:block" is the default anyway.

Comment: Yep, don't need to declare it. :) The answer provided here is good, clear: both. :)

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you use display:flex on the parent ul.
Then its `flex-direction:column` for a vertical layout.

Comment: There is no `ul` anywhere in the author's code so that won't be a solution. It's also recommended to add an explanation how this would work, i.e. point to the W3C documentation or a tutorial.